# how to change port number of Apache server in windows OS

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, windows-xp, xampp

I have installed xampp control panel and Apache 2.2 on windows XP
when I  type http://localhost/ gives me page which says It Works!

Now, I want to change the port number 80 to some other number

How to change it ?
in how many files does it needs to be changed ?
dose it require to restart the system to change to take effect ?

Note: I have changed port number in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

in two places where it says

`Listen 80`

and

`ServerName localhost:80`

Pls help,
thanks.

Comment: Edit your "httpd.conf" file and replace the number 80 to whatever you like, e.g, 90 in "Listen 80" so this would change to "Listen 90".

Answer (score 10):

Please go to the

> httpd.conf

and change

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 8080
```

or any port.

Remember to allow that port through `firewall` and you have `restart the Apache service` not the system.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your `httpd.conf` file and on about like 40ish change:

```
Listen 80
```

to:

```
Listen 1234
```

Or whatever port you choose!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but maybe this helps someone..

If you are running in a virtual host environment, just change the top line of the virtual host directive:

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:18080>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain-18080"
</VirtualHost>
```

You will still need to add the listen 18080 directive in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

1 Open Httpd.conf file from (c:/xamp/apache/conf) and edit Replace the words

**Listen 80 to  Listen 8080**

2 **ServerName localhost:80  To ServerName localhost:8080**
And save the file.

3. Open the file httpd-ssl.conf  from (c:/ xamp/apache/conf/extra). for edit ssl port number to 8081 So need to replace

**Listen 443 To Listen 8081**

```
**<VirtualHost _default_:443> To <VirtualHost _default_:8081>**
```

**ServerName localhost:8013 To ServerName localhost:8081**

Save File

4. Open Xamp
5. Go to Config -> Service and Port Settings -> Appache
6. **Change Main port to 8080 and SSL Port to 8081**

[More in Details](https://unclecoder.com/article/Apache-server/44/Apache-Change-Port-No-Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your apache-tomcat Installation folder there you find conf folder inside that server.xml file will be there.. You can change the port number and configuration setting for your server.

> Drive:\apache-tomcat\conf\server.xml

Answer (score 0):

thanks for response

but only changing port number in:  **C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf**
didn't work (apache couldn't start)

so with above mention change,

we have to change port number in another file to make it work

i have changed in  :  C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

in above file
find

(if port number you want is 85)

Listen 443

change it to

Listen 85

find

change it to

find

ServerName localhost:443

change it to

ServerName localhost:85

the port number in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf   and   C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf   should be different.

restart Apache service in XAMPP Control Panel 
and type in your browses address bar : http://localhost:'port number'/

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy .You need to make few changes to httpd.conf file as follows:
Listen 80 to  Listen 8080
and
ServerName localhost:80  to ServerName localhost:8080

For more detailed info with screenshots ,you can refer this - http://www.superpctricks.com/2013/11/running-iis-and-apache-on-same-server.html

Comment: Please summarize the article that you linked, quoting any relevant code segments or configuration blocks.  Sites can change in the future or fail to load for any number of reasons.